# What fonts are used in this formula?

Tags: fonts

I have been trying to match the following style for some work I am doing but can't see to match the various font weights very well. Does anyone know which fonts are being used?

[image]

In particular I can't seem to get the curly l, the 5 pointed asterisk and the right kerning between the fn and x.

Comment: You can get the "curly l" by typing `\ell`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's Helvetica and Courier - probably from using a Times font package `\usepackage{mathptmx}` (they tend to pull Helvetica and Courier for sans serif and monospaced text). The curly "C" looks like a usual `\mathcal`. The double brackets are probably from `stmaryrd.sty` and are called `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`. The star is `\star`. And the curly l is `\ell`.

Comment: The kerning between `fn` and "x" is probably obtained by `\mathop{\mathtt{fn}}x`