# Double square brackets

Tags: symbols, equations

In many equation editors (e.g. MS Word 2007 and Daum Equation Editor), there's a double square bracket. Is there a TeX equivalent for `[[`, `((`, `))`, and `]]`?

Comment: Did you mean the double brackets like in the picture in this question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48310/what-fonts-are-used-in-this-formula/

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a multiset parenthesis pair in any of the standard fonts. See this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5816/multiset-notation-in-latex/

Comment: yes that double brackets. but also for ((A,B))!

Comment: For double parentheses see this question: [A symbol for the field of formal Laurent series](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4616).

Comment: The package [`stmaryrd`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) seems to have the symbols you're looking for.  `llparenthesis`, `llbracket` for example.

Comment: @SeanAllred Your comment seems to be an answer

Comment: @egreg indeed it does :P It was way past my bedtime though ;)

Comment: Link to related questions —
■ [`‖ ‖`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/616861)
■ [`‖ ‖` (extensible)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57945)
■ [`( ‖ )`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151984)
■ [`〚〛`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308973)
■ [`⟪ | ⟫`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32794)
■ [`⟪ ⟫`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12464)
■ [`⟪ ⟫` without MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79657)
■ [`⟪ ⟫` `〚〛` `⦇ ⦈ ⦃ ⦄`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412543)
■ [`‖ ⟫`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625880)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you only want then occasionally, perhaps you can just roll-your-own by using a little bit of negative space, like this

```
Maths in double brackets $[\![ e=mc^2 ]\!]$ or double parentheses $(\!( a^2 )\!)$.
```

[image: negspace output]

Note that they will not scale nicely with `\left` and `\right` because of the fixed negative space.

---

If you'll be using them *a lot*, try using a package like [`stmaryrd`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) that defines commands for these symbols, as recommended in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \llbracket     1 \rrbracket       \quad
  \llparenthesis 2 \rrparenthesis   \quad
  \llceil        3 \rrceil          \quad
  \llfloor       4 \rrfloor         \quad
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: stmaryrd output]

Note especially the fancier display for double parentheses.

As a side note, [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is getting better and better at recognizing these symbols, so you can check there for more package-based options.

Comment: thanks. for double parentheses I prefer the inner line be a curve to some extent like this one http://i.stack.imgur.com/bVfPz.png. however \llparenthesis is good.

Comment: Another option (from Detexify) is `\textlbrackdbl` and `\textrbrackdbl` from `\usepackage{textcomp}`. My markdown editor includes this package but not `stmaryrd` which is handy!

Answer (score 12):

These commands are `\lBrack`/`\rBrack`, and either `\lParen` and `\rParen` or `\llparenthesis` and `\rrparenthesis` in `unicode-math` or several 8-bit packages, including `stix`, `stix2` and `fdsymbol`.  In Unicode, you can also use the symbols `⟦`, `⦅`, `⦇`, etc.

You might find the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from `mathtools` very convenient, especially if you need to specify a size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern} % Loads unicode-math

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Brackets{\lBrack}{\rBrack}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Parens{\lParen}{\rParen}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
   \lBrack x \rBrack \quad \lParen y \rParen \quad
   \llparenthesis z \rrparenthesis \\
   \Brackets{u} \quad \Parens{v}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

Comment: `\lParen` and `\rParen` look much nicer than `\rrparenthesis` and `\rrparenthesis`!

Answer (score 5):

In the case that you would have a conflict between [stmaryrd](https://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) and another package, or that you dislike some redefinitions of symbols (such as \bigtriangledown), you may want to use the following line to import only the commands that you wish:

```latex
\usepackage[only,llbracket,rrbracket]{stmaryrd}
```