# Typesetting double brackets and double parentheses

Tags: equations

I need the LaTeX equation with double square bracket and double paranthesis. Can anyone suggest me the proper code? Here, I had attached the screenshots.
[image]

Comment: The `stmaryrd` package has `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` which would cover your first example.  See http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107252/double-square-brackets)

Comment: @C.F.G -- The double parentheses shown in that link don't scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In favour of Consistent typography, I always suggest creating a command that generates a certain output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\llrrbracket}[1]{% \llrrbracket{..}
  \left[\mkern-3mu\left[#1\right]\mkern-3mu\right]}
\newcommand{\llrrparen}[1]{% \llrrparen{..}
  \left(\mkern-6mu\left(#1\right)\mkern-6mu\right)}
\begin{document}
\[
  \llrrbracket{\frac{1}{x}} \quad \mbox{in the case }
  P_\infty = F_p\llrrparen{\frac{1}{x}}
\]
\end{document}
```

You can, of course, play around with the choice of `\mkern`, which brings the two elements together.

Comment: This is a nice way to do it!

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{stmaryrd}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \bigg\llbracket \frac{1}{x}\bigg\rrbracket  \text{ in the case } P_\infty = \mathbb{F}_p \left(\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)\right)
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:

I have updated the code to contain the suggestion given in the comment. The above code uses the `stmaryrd` package.