# How can I reduce spacing between parenthesis

Tags: spacing, equations

How can I reduce space between parenthesis?

For example:

[image]

How can I reduce the space marked by the red?

Comment: Kerning? As in [a previously posted answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126288/16595)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Oh, I had not seen that. I should read answers fully next time :) and yes, that is what I mean.