# How do I define norm delimiters?

Tags: equations, symbols, math-operators

I would like to write the following equation in LaTeX:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
       R =  \left\Vert\norm\overrightarrow{q_1c}\right\Vert=\left\Vert\norm\overrightarrow{q_2c}\right\Vert
\end{equation}
```

Although the result as my expectation, I meet the "Undefined control Sequence" error:

[image]

Could you help me fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to load `\usepackage{amsmath}`? Also `\norm` is not a common LaTeX command; did you define it?

Comment: Hi  imnothere, I find usepackage{amsmath is available on my Latex template: \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

Comment: What about `\norm`? If you delete `\norm` from your code, it already compiles and the output is already similar to your screenshot. So perhaps you don't need the `\norm` at all?

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Related/duplicates: [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43008/5764); [Double vertical bar notation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151984/5764)

Comment: Thank @ Werner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've been informed that `\norm` is an "undefined control sequence". You further mention, in a comment, that you load the `amsmath` and `amssymb` packages. (Aside: Since the `amssymb` package loads the `amsfonts` package automatically, you don't need to load the `amsfonts` package explicitly.)

You have two main options:

1. Remove the two `\norm` directives from the code. And, while you're at it, do remove the `\left` and `\right` sizing directives as well, as they don't do anything here except create code clutter.

   ```
   \documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
   \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
   \usepackage{old-arrows} % optional (for smaller arrowheads) 

   \begin{document}
   \begin{equation}
       R = \Vert\overrightarrow{q_1c}\Vert = \Vert\overrightarrow{q_2c}\Vert
   \end{equation}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Remove the `\left\Vert` and `\right\Vert` directives and define a macro called `\norm`. I'd like to suggest you load the `mathtools` package -- a superset of the `amsmath` package -- for its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro to define `\norm`.

   ```
   \documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
   \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
   \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert} % define a "\norm" macro
   \usepackage{old-arrows} % optional (for smaller arrowheads) 

   \begin{document}
   \begin{equation}
       R = \norm{\overrightarrow{q_1c}} = \norm{\overrightarrow{q_2c}}
   \end{equation}
   \end{document}
   ```

With both approaches, you'll get the following output:

[image]

Of the two approaches, the second is definitely more "LaTeX-y" as the code (here: `\norm{...}`) emphasizes the *meaning* of what you're inputting. This conforms better to LaTeX's design philosophy of distinguishing as much as possible between higher-level meaning and lower-level typesetting aspects of the code.

Comment: Hi Mico, thank you so much for your detail answer.

Comment: @PHỦĐỗTường Consider "upvote" and "accept" the answer when it solved your problem.