# Typesetting equivalence class with latex

Tags: symbols

I was wondering, I haven't been able to find the symbol for doing a "hollow" square bracket, its basically how you would expect a square bracket to look if you used \mathbb on it. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Hello! This symbol can be found both by detexify and in symbols-a4.pdf, and one option how to obtain it is by `\llbracket` from `\usepackage{stmaryrd}`.

Comment: see [Double square brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107252/579)

Comment: @JustDanyul: This is not a standard way to denote an equivalence class!