# How can I have a big $[\![ \overrightarrow{\mathcal A} ]\!]$?

Tags: brackets

I would like to have the double square-brackets that are scaled up according to the symbol inside `[\![ \overrightarrow{\mathcal A} ]\!]`. I tried `\left [\![ \overrightarrow{\mathcal A} ]\! \right]`, but to no avail. How can I do so?

[image]

`$\left [\!\left[ \overrightarrow{\mathcal A} \right]\!\right]$` will separate the double bracket (as in below image). I want to keep them share the same horizontal edge:

[image]

Comment: Does `$\left [\!\left[ \overrightarrow{\mathcal A} \right]\!\right]$` solve?

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela `$\left [\!\left[ \overrightarrow{\mathcal A} \right]\!\right]$` will separate the double bracket. I want to keep them share the same horizontal edge.

Comment: several fonts have a real double bracket so you don't need to use `[\![` and it scales as a single character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK your solution is this. Use the `stmaryrd` package that has useful bracket and parentheses styles.

So the code should be this `$\left\llbracket\overrightarrow{\mathcal A} \right\rrbracket$`. This allows the brackets to share common edges as well as scale up.

[image: Scaled up bracket]

This is adapted from here: [Double square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107252/double-square-brackets/107464) with slight modification for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The double brackets are `\lBrack` and `rBrack` in several packages, including `unicode-math`, `stix`, `stix2` and `fdsymbol`.  A convenient way to use them is in a paired math delimiter from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Brackets{\lBrack}{\rBrack}

\begin{document}
\[ \Brackets*{\overrightarrow{\mathcal A}\;}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

You can manually specify the size of the brackets with, e.g., `\Brackets[\big]`.  Here, I added a bit of space on the right to compensate for the arrow smashing into the right delimiter, which is not a great solution.

You could also adjust the position of the arrow with `\skew`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Brackets{\lBrack}{\rBrack}
\newcommand\Aaarow{\skew{-2}\overrightarrow{\mathcal{A}}}

\begin{document}
\[ \Brackets*{\Aaarow}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

Or you could use a font whose `\overrightarrow` does not extend as far, such as STIX Two Math.