Geometric measure theory: Notation for currents over oriented manifolds [[M]]
In the book "Introduction to geometric measure theory" by Simon, the author uses a kind of double square bracket notation for currents over oriented $C^1$ manifolds, something like this [[M]] however it's not exactly the notation of the current M on the left hand side  as the picture shows, and I haven't been able to find any reference online
.

Does this answer your question? LaTeX code for "white square brackets" 〚 and 〛 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107252/double-square-brackets

yes it does, thank you very much.
